# Uncaught exception in PassengerServer client thread

Tags: nginx, passenger

on a CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final), I've this problem with passenger 3.0.9:

```
[ pid=3332 thr=16838960 file=abstract_request_handler.rb:466 time=2011-11-16 23:54:10.795 ]: Accepting new request on main socket
[ pid=2894 thr=139811053770496 file=ext/nginx/HelperAgent.cpp:933 time=2011-11-16 23:54:10.958 ]: Uncaught exception in PassengerServer client thread:
   exception: write() failed: Connection reset by peer (104)
   backtrace:
     in 'void Client::forwardResponse(Passenger::SessionPtr&, Passenger::FileDescriptor&, const Passenger::AnalyticsLogPtr&)' (HelperAgent.cpp:705)
     in 'void Client::handleRequest(Passenger::FileDescriptor&)' (HelperAgent.cpp:859)
     in 'void Client::threadMain()' (HelperAgent.cpp:952)

[ pid=4135 thr=16838960 file=abstract_request_handler.rb:466 time=2011-11-16 23:54:12.710 ]: Accepting new request on main socket
```

What can be? Im sure my app works well because on others machines haven't problems, I tried also passenger edge and latest nginx. The app is a 2.3.11 rails application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found myself, we need to remove proxy_temp files, this probably because upgrading from a version of nginx to another break somethings. So my solution (for now):

`rm -rf /etc/nginx/proxy_temp/*`

Answer (score 0):

What is the maximum number of open files allowed on your system? You can check that using `ulimit -n`. Could you please check if increasing that value in `/etc/sysctl.conf` helps you?